# How to handle LDAP connection?

Tags: java, ldap

I'm trying to implement the following:

I have an Importer class which registers so called `Processor`s, and then executes them by iterating over them and calling execute (`Processor` is an interface and contains a method `void execute()`).

What those processors do is connect to an LDAP, and do certain tasks, e.g. retrieves a list of persons and stores them into a database, or reads certain privileges and maps them to groups.

This all works out quite well... except I just don't know how to handle the LDAP connection.

Here are some ideas:

1. initialize the connection in the constructor (and assign it to a field) and provide a dispose()` method, which closes the connection **or**
2. do not initialize the connection field in the constructor, but initialize and close it in the `execute()` method **or**
3. create the connection in the execute method and pass it to all methods which are called
4. even uglier (create the connection in the Importer and pass it to all processors, then, after execution, close it)

Comment: #2 imo, keep it as simple as possible for the Importer, and don't keep connections open for longer than needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the connection to the LDAP server with a Strategy method that is a required parameter. This de-couples and isolates the code. You should prefer the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) for this work - and the SDK supports  the ability to create an [in-memory directory server](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/ldap-in-memory-directory-server-using-unboundid-ldap-sdk/) so there is no need to use "mock" or "fake" connections. Also, you can examine the blog post ["LDAP: Programming Practices"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/).

Comment: +1 I already use UnboundID LDAP SDK as well as the InMemory DS - it's great! Could you elaborate a bit about the Strategy Pattern part? I know and regularly use the Strategy pattern but don't know how to apply it here.

Comment: Just a thought. Create a ServerConnectionStrategy interface that defines services that must be provided by a service provider (where the service provider is a group of classes that provide the necessary LDAP services). The strategy defines the services which are implemented elsewhere. I am thinking of the 'execute()' method to use the pattern. I am not a fan of methods that don't take any parameters to indicate their function - polymorphism can be taken too far and can make the code brittle. If execute() takes a strategy parameter, it's role is clearer. I have not really thought this through.

Answer (score 1):

Build it somewhere else and inject it into the application.

If you don't have JEE6 which provides dependency injection via CDDI then you can use Spring framework as a workaround.

It has two benefits.

1. the lifecycle of the connection is outside the class that uses it
2. the connection can be replaced with a mock or fake connection for testing.